# Redis: Cluster To Cluster (another) Replication

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis, redis-cluster

Is there any mechanism to replicate the whole Redis cluster to another?

Example: I have Redis Cluster RC1 which has n master nodes and m slaves. I also have Redis Cluster RC2 with a similar configuration to RC1. Now I want to replicate data (whole/delta) from RC1 to RC2.

Comment: Do you need both sites to be active (for writes) to the second site is read only?

Comment: No, only one cluster I need for writes.. another cluster is to read only..